# Using the "aggregate" function for drawing line plots

Tags: r, aggregate, line-plot

I am trying to draw a line plot with error bars for two groups of data (Treatment vs. Control).  There are totally 20 periods, 10 Trial Periods (TP) and 10 formal Periods (P) and I want to show how the group means change over time.  For simplicity, the following dataframe includes 3 Trial Periods (TP1, TP5, TP10) and 3 formal Periods (P1, P5, P10).

Below is my code.  My problem is that the “aggregate” function changes the order of the periods by resorting them as strings, which messes up the time trend—I want them to be ordered as TP1->TP5->TP10->P1->P5->P10

I suppose this is not too tricky, but I’m just stuck.  I’d appreciate it if someone could tell me how to solve this problem.

Also: as there are 20 periods in total, it might look better to draw error bands (or CI bands) instead of numerous error bars.  Is there a way to do this?

```
df <- data.frame(Condition=c(rep("Treatment", 10), rep("Control", 10)), 
               TP1=rnorm(20, 1, 1), TP5=rnorm(20, 5, 1), TP10=rnorm(20, 10, 1), 
               P1=rnorm(20, 1, 1), P5=rnorm(20, 5, 1), P10=rnorm(20, 10, 1))

temp <- tidyr::gather(df, Period, x, -Condition)

m <- aggregate(x~Period + Condition, temp, mean)

st.err <- function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x))

se <- aggregate(x~Period + Condition, temp, st.err)

ci.data <- cbind(m, se[, 3])

colnames(ci.data) <-  c("Period", "Condition", "Mean", "SE")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=ci.data, aes(x=Period, y=Mean, group=Condition, color=Condition)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +  
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SE, ymax=Mean + SE), 
                width=.1, position=position_dodge(0.05))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [format code you provide properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738). This time we took care about it. See [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `reshape2::melt()` converts the periods into factors which are better sorting. There is no need for more aggregation here, since `geom_smooth()` is doing what you want.

```
df.long <- reshape2::melt(df, "Condition", variable.name="Period", value.name = "x")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.long, aes(x=Period, y=x, group=Condition, color=Condition, fill=Condition)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", level=0.95, alpha=.2)
```

***Yielding***

[image]

***Data***

```
set.seed(42)  # for sake of reproducibility
df <- data.frame(Condition=c(rep("Treatment", 10), rep("Control", 10)), 
               TP1=rnorm(20, 1, 1), TP5=rnorm(20, 5, 1), TP10=rnorm(20, 10, 1), 
               P1=rnorm(20, 1, 1), P5=rnorm(20, 5, 1), P10=rnorm(20, 10, 1))
```

***Edit***

For your larger dataset you could adjust the smoothing with `span`. Export the plot e.g. with `png()` to your [working directory](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html).

```
png("test.png", width=1080, height=720, res=100)
ggplot(df.long, aes(x=Period, y=x, group=Condition, color=Condition, fill=Condition)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", level=0.95, alpha=.2, span=.2) +
  labs(title="My Plot")
dev.off()
```

***Yielding***

[image]

Comment: Thanks, brilliant!  I encounter some problems when applying the code to my larger dataset, though.  There are two main issues, first there are actually 28 periods and the width of the plot is too narrow to fit them nicely in, and this seems to be exacerbated by the second problem.  The second problem is: the means of the Treatment groups at times change dramatically (plunges, etc.), but the output plot smoothes these changes and obscures the sharp changes I want to show.  Here's a link to the bigger dataset https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruxxujd4byt4ste/df.csv?dl=0.  Really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: See my edit. You're probably talking about the preview window in RStudio (which you can scale with the mouse). I'm sure you want to export the plot, e.g. with `?png`, `?pdf`, or `?ggsave`. Does this work for you?

Comment: Great! Now then on Stack Overflow it's common to mark the answer as accepted and to gain **+2** reputation. Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green (see [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/371738)).

Comment: I just did it.  Thanks for teaching me about this!  Really appreciate your help.